# programa para calcular determinantes de matrices cuadradas python resuelve algunos determinantes incorrectamente

Tags: python, matrices

Al probar mi código he descubierto que hay una matriz en la que al calcular el determinante,muestra el resultado incorrecto.

¿Alguien sabe cuál es el error?

Generalmente lo calcula bien,pero no siempre.A la hora de introducir cada elemento de la matriz,tienes que ponerlos por columnas,no por filas;es decir,de arriba a abajo(luego pasarias a introducir los elementos de la siguiente columna,tambien empezando por arriba hacia abajo)

Por ejemplo, el determinante de esta matriz lo resuelve mal:

```
(0 4 -2 4 )
(-6 2 10 0)
(5 8 -5 2)
(0 -2 1 0)
```

en este caso, el determinante es `392`,pero el programa devuelve `-0`

```
#Variables

matriz = []


#Funciones

    def mat(n):
        for i in range (n):
            matriz.append([])
            for j in range (n):
                matriz[i].append(0)
        return matriz

    def llenar(n):
        matriz = mat(n)
        for x in range (n):
            for y in range (n):
                matriz[x][y] = float(input('Valor de [' + str(x) + '][' + str(y) + '] = '))

    def gauss(n):
        for z in range (n-1):
            for x in range(1, n-z):
                if (matriz[z][z] != 0 ):
                    p = matriz[x+z][z] / matriz[z][z]
                    for y in range (n):
                        matriz[x+z][y] = matriz[x+z][y] - (matriz[z][y]*p)

    def det(n):
        deter=1
        for x in range (n):
            deter=matriz[x][x]*deter
        print ('\nEl determinante de la matriz es = ', deter)

    def im(n):
        print("\nMatriz resultante:")
        for i in range (n):
                print (matriz[i][:])

#Programa

    n = int(input ('Tamano de la matriz : '))
    llenar(n)
    gauss(n)
    det(n)
    im(n)
    input()
```

Comment: podrias agregar los casos en que no te calcula bien

Comment: Si es una opción, puedes usar `np.linalg.det(matriz)` de _numpy_  `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Lo he pensado,pero mi profesor nos ha prohibido usar ayudas como numpy,tengo que hacerlo a mano.

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor hacerlo por numpy de python. Tiene modulos que tratan esto. Tambien te comento que ya esto esta programado de manera recursiva por menores.
El codigo no lleva en cuenta los posibles ceros en la diagonal principal. He heho unos cambios para controlar esto y en los casos que he hecho vale. Ponlo a prueba con una bateria de casos.

## CALCULO DEL DETERMINANTE POR METODO DE GAUSS

matriz = []

## Inicio entrada de datos

def mat(n):
    for i in range(n):
        matriz.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            matriz[i].append(0)
    return matriz

def llenar(n):
    matriz = mat(n)
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            matriz[x][y] = float(input('Valor de [' + str(x) + '][' + str(y) + '] = '))
        print()
    # Fin entrada de datos
    # Muestra entrada datos
    print('Matriz : ')
    for i in range(n):
        print(matriz[i][:])

def gauss(n):
    inv = 0  # Conteo de cambios
    for z in range(n - 1):
        for x in range(1, n - z):
            # Aqui cambio de filas cuando ceros en diagonal
            q = z
            while matriz[q][z] == 0 and q < n - 1:
                temp = matriz[q][:]
                matriz[q][:] = matriz[q + 1][:]
                matriz[q + 1][:] = temp
                inv += 1
                q += 1
            # Aqui metodo de gauss
            if (matriz[z][z] != 0):
                p = matriz[x + z][z] / matriz[z][z]
                for y in range(n):
                    matriz[x + z][y] = matriz[x + z][y] - (matriz[z][y] * p)
                    # Muestra matriz de Gauss (Upper)
    print('Matriz por Gauss : ')
    for i in range(n):
        print(matriz[i][:])
        # Calculo determinante
    deter = 1
    for x in range(n):
        deter = matriz[x][x] * deter
    print('\nEl determinante de la matriz es = ', deter * (-1) ** inv)

## Inicio de bloques : Programa

n = int(input('Tamaño de la matriz : '))
print()
llenar(n)
gauss(n)